# VBA to work on all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I tried many different sample codes before posting this, but I can't get any of them to work.

I need this to run not just in the active sheet but on all sheets in my file.

```
On Error Resume Next
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Hope someone is able to help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop over the sheets in the workbook and manipulate each one individually:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sheet.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Alex K. is OK, only check if the sheet is empty or not, otherwise you will have an error with "SpecialCells" :

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        sheet.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just check the count on column A since that is the only column user cares about?